# Mysql Query wont echo all results! PHP

Tags: php, mysql

My code goes like this,

```
$sql = "SELECT Month(time) as Month, Year(time) as Year,
title, COUNT(*) AS total FROM posts GROUP BY Year, Month ORDER BY time DESC";

$stmt = $conn->query($sql);

if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $stmt->fetch_array()){
  echo "<div class=title>" . $row["title"]. "</div>";
}
}
```

it is supposed to output 4 titles,

```
Bellavisa
Mist Neting
Turkey is cool!
Cock of the Rock
```

but it only outputs

```
Bellavisa

Turkey is cool!

Cock of the Rock
```

Note that bellavisa and mist neting are in the same year and month, (setting up an archive list)

EDIT

Here is some of the table data

```
title "bellavisa" content "yadadada" time "timestamp ..." Author "author"   

title "mist nesting" content "yadadada" time "timestamp ..." Author "author"
```

Comment: Why is title not in the group by? Duh.

Comment: You're using aliases, so `Month(time) as Month` => `$row["Month"]` etc.

Comment: You're also GROUPing the results with an aggregate function, so something can get snipped out.

Comment: this is just a partial part of the code, having title in the group by eliminates it all together it seems from my archive listing 2010 - September should have 2 posts in it and it says it does but it only lists one, when I include title in the group by it only says it has one post in September and it lists the bellavisa

Comment: @Mario is there a way to group it a different way so it wont snip out posts in the same month? it counts them correctly but doesn't echo them

Comment: My guess is MySQL is implicitly including `title` in the `GROUP BY` because that's what it does. Can you provide some sample data from your `posts` table?

Comment: If you already knew the cause, then include that in your question. The more precise you are, the more precise answers can be. Cut out "thanks" and "pls help me" etc.

Comment: @Phil title "bellavisa" content "yadadada" time "timestamp ..." Author "author"  title "mist nesting" content "yadadada" time "timestamp ..." Author "author"

Comment: @Ignacious See the ["edit"](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28333820/edit) link underneath your question's tags? Use it. Comments are not a place for code / data

Comment: What if `... posts GROUP BY Year, Month ORDER BY ...` replace to `... posts GROUP BY Year, Month, title ORDER BY ...` ?

Comment: @RubahMalam I have done that before but then it messes up the counts, it says the month of September has 1 and not 2

Comment: Why don't you set up a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with **real** data and explain what you'd like to see as a result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, `title` is per post, so to get all the titles you should use no `GROUP BY`, while `COUNT(*)` is per month, so to get counts you need to `GROUP BY` the way you do, so in a simple `SELECT` you can either select one or another, but not both.

To select both, you need to use a subquery, something along the lines of

```php
$sql = "SELECT Month(time) as Month, Year(time) as Year, title, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM posts WHERE Month(time) = Month AND Year(time) = Year) AS total FROM posts ORDER BY time DESC;";
```

Effectively, the query selects all the posts, and for each post computes a count. It is not the most efficient way to do that, you can rewrite it using a join, if every post has a unique ID. But for a table with reasonable size this query will work just fine.

Comment: Thank you, Sir. You have helped tremendously!